# how to use on value from the form for multiple errors

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I have a password field that i need to compare to different validation steps.

this is how i did it

```
errors.password = {};
if (!values.password) {
    errors.password.main = "Password is required"
} 
else {
  if(values.password.length < 7) errors.password.min = true
  if(!(/[a-z]/.test(values.password))) errors.password.uc = true
  if(!(/[0-9]/.test(values.password))) errors.password.num = true
  if(!(/[^A-Za-z0-9]/.test(values.password))) errors.password.sc = true    
}
if(Object.keys(errors.password).length === 0) errors.password = undefined
```

and it should be bound to this:

```
    <input {...input} .../> // errors.password.main
    <div>
      <ValidPasswordContainer img={pwErr} text="One lower case character" />
      <ValidPasswordContainer img={pwErr} text="One number" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <ValidPasswordContainer img={pwErr} text="One special number" />
      <ValidPasswordContainer img={pwErr} text="8 character minimum" />
    </div>
```

what would be the correct way to return the object so that the validation is successful and it renders the errors?

This is the error i get: 
`Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {main}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please clarify your code samples with their respective usages. Provide where they exist and how are they called upon.

Comment: It's basically the same as the renderField component with those few added divs

Comment: why you don't use array of validation functions like in this example https://redux-form.com/7.3.0/examples/fieldlevelvalidation/ ?